# OpenCV 3.1 installation error on PyDev on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos, python-3.x, opencv, pydev

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.1 with Python 3.5 on Mac OS X Sierra. Using the many helpful tutorials around, I managed to use terminal and Homebrew to install it. More specifically, I used the following:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
```

I also used the following to install python 3.5 and numpy respectively:

```
brew install python3
brew install numpy --with-python3
```

Installation appears to be successful, as when I run the following on terminal, I get no error:

```
python3
import cv2
```

Furthermore, I can see the opencv3 and python3.5 files in my local directory as follows:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3 
/usr/local/Cellar/python3
```

Now when I tried to install PyDev (experienced trouble in that as well, but eventually succeeded!) with Eclipse, OpenCV appears to fail. Basic commands such as:

```
print("hello world")
```

work as expected. When I try the following however, I don't seem to be so lucky.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('obj4_4.jpg',0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

More specifically, I get the following error:

"OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the          library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 545
Traceback (most recent call last):"

I tried long and hard to find a workaround, but they all seem to be centered around Linux/Windows. Any help provided would be appreciated, as I think it would help the whole community!